# How many times can someone listen to a song before he/she stops enjoying it?

Tags: sensation, music, hearing

How many repetitions do we need to get tired of listening to a song over and over again? I want to know if some kind of average number of repetitions exisits.

Is there any research related to this question? Or is there no need to put this in the context of a song. Any "repetition" is OK, say, speaking a sentence over and over, eating same food again and again, etc.

Comment: No.... Hmm... Now I'm thinking maybe it is impossible to categorize this kind of stuff...

Comment: Music is diverse, and music-listening is personal; thus it is perhaps impossible to come up with a general number that supposedly measures a predefined repetitive limit, after which every song potentially becomes boring or unpleasant or unappealing. A simple answer to your question is: "No."

Comment: I don't think this question is particularly well framed. As the OP noticed and @GaneshKarapakula commented, there is a built in assumption in this question that is not supported by any [initial research](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/66/29) on the part of the OP. I have voted to close this as NaRQ. However, I encourage the OP to revise the question into something that assumes less or is framed by existing research.

Comment: There's probably some more specific stuff here to do with habituation, but I think you'd be hard pressed to put a specific number on it without some thorough studies.

Comment: Perhaps have a read through: Pachet, F. Hit Song Science. In Tao, Tzanetakis & Ogihara, editor, Music Data Mining, pages 305-326, Chapman & Hall / CRC Press. 2011.